# Шаблон ASP.NET Core Web Api. .NET 6

Tags: c#, .net

При создании проекта WebApi создаётся такой шаблон:

```
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

// Add services to the container.

builder.Services.AddControllers();
// Learn more about configuring Swagger/OpenAPI at https://aka.ms/aspnetcore/swashbuckle
builder.Services.AddEndpointsApiExplorer();
builder.Services.AddSwaggerGen();

var app = builder.Build();

// Configure the HTTP request pipeline.
if (app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
    app.UseSwagger();
    app.UseSwaggerUI();
}

app.UseHttpsRedirection();

app.UseAuthorization();

app.MapControllers();

app.Run();
```

Я слышал, что в новых версиях C# не обязательно использовать класс Program и метод Main, но у меня вопрос, откуда компилятор знает о классе `WebApplication`, если нигде не используется `using`.

Comment: наиболее часто используемые юзинги подключены автоматически в новом синтаксисе, просто это скрыто за синтаксическим сахаром. Посмотрите [вот тут](https://sharplab.io/#v2:D4AQTAjAsAUCEE4AUAiFBKA3EA==)

Comment: @Kalmankantaja они подключены глобально в автогенерируемом файле `obj/Debug/net6.0/*.GlobalUsings.g.cs`, ссылка на sharplab.io неуместна

Comment: @iiKuzmychov у меня такого файла нет, однако я использую implicit using

Comment: Благодарю за разъяснения

Comment: @Kalmankantaja - в Visual Studio в Solution Explorer нажать кнопку Show All Files.

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov да, уже нашел, не в той папке смотрел